# Kendo scheduler timeline time interval

Tags: kendo-ui, size, scheduler, timeline

Is there a way to change the size of kendo timeline header cells.  I need to create a condensed scheduler like the prototype below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use `height` and `views/eventHeight` like so:

```
views: [
    {
        type: "timeline",
        eventHeight: 10
    }
],
height: 280,
```

Example: http://dojo.telerik.com/oZiZA

Tell me what exacly do you need if you need something more.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reduce the number of columns you can adjust the minorTickCount option:

- [minorTickCount](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#configuration-minorTickCount)